# php big integers

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to work with big numbers in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490888/how-to-work-with-big-numbers-in-php)

i am developing a web app on RSA algorithm.
as to make RSA more secure u have to use large numbers so here it goes....
so first i convert the alphabets (all A to Z) into their ASCII codes, i m using ord().

but the problem is the function `ciphertext=m(pow)e*[mod n]`
in which m (message which is a number) to the power e is to be calculated
now if ascii of a is 97 , and suppose e=57
then 97 to the power 57 will be huge....
i have a 32 bit laptop.

so plz tell the right data type which i should use
thanks.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490888/how-to-work-with-big-numbers-in-php

Comment: is 32 but lappy make any difference ...idk..let me know if it does ??

Comment: one of my friend said that 64 bit supports big ints

Comment: Did you read the manual at all?  No need for conjecture:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 0):

Don't roll your own encryption.

Take a look at [the OpenSSL extension](http://php.net/book.openssl), [shelling out to the `openssl` binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337644/168868), or the [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) if you don't have either the OpenSSL extension or binary installed.