# encrypt and decrypt with phpseclib using rsa public and private key , getting decryption error

Tags: php, phpseclib

phpseclib:

php code :

```
include('Crypt/RSA_XML.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA_XML();

$rsa->loadKeyfromXML($public_key_xml);

$data = "invoice_number=1,100.00&customer_tin=674858994885&serial=ONLYPEMPSERIAL&tin=ONLYPUMPTIN&vat_1_net=2,0000&vat_1_value=3600&vat_2_net=0&vat_2_value=0&vat_3_net=0&vat_3_value=0&vat_4_net=0&vat_4_value=0&vat_5_net=0&vat_5_value=0&vat_6_net=0&vat_6_value=0&vat_7_net=0&vat_7_value=0&vat_8_net=0&vat_8_value=0&payment_mode=3&discount=200&total_gross=9562";
$plaintext = $data;

//define('CRYPT_RSA_PKCS15_COMPAT', true);

$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

$ciphertext = base64_encode(strrev($rsa->encrypt($plaintext)));

echo "data";

echo $ciphertext; // there is encoded value getting
```

and
then how to decrypt encrypted data using private key:
echo $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext); // this is giving error , decryption error

actually , i want to encrypt in php and decrypt in c# , 
data encrypted successfully and when c# rsa crypto service decrypt this encrypted data then giving error message : invalid base-64 string length

```
$public_key_xml and $private_key_xml is defined below...
```

**public key :**

```
 <RSAKeyValue>        
    <Modulus>uidt3bPfWozkIkC6nHnRDbXrvjqplfCslV2zP4hKJ6sVjVnPfjMM0ueCuEDFZ9NK+kCWaPNAVhOKKwL8HmoX/7KcFLWkwSoatnrncHTH5STey+bqR1xTFY+Rubj8BZt7D9JJYyLQC46wn4ySVnLWkCZZ9+aaTriEBzGTpUzeRiUTWVprp3oXsA7ZKyn+lhZfMx1ILhcD8dnX7xFHB57jIKvPBxAdT4K7GxdgENeS76I/zmVmlF//JnmtZ/RM1WmRkx8mFmcK/Ky8gLsmIpPPltoyBWIKIf2NQH9kHqHa2gwoPg34LTutV9AACTWuiVOjqU7Gq2BHQcjovXMF8t3Wiw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

**private key :**

```
 <RSAKeyValue>        
    <Modulus>uidt3bPfWozkIkC6nHnRDbXrvjqplfCslV2zP4hKJ6sVjVnPfjMM0ueCuEDFZ9NK+kCWaPNAVhOKKwL8HmoX/7KcFLWkwSoatnrncHTH5STey+bqR1xTFY+Rubj8BZt7D9JJYyLQC46wn4ySVnLWkCZZ9+aaTriEBzGTpUzeRiUTWVprp3oXsA7ZKyn+lhZfMx1ILhcD8dnX7xFHB57jIKvPBxAdT4K7GxdgENeS76I/zmVmlF//JnmtZ/RM1WmRkx8mFmcK/Ky8gLsmIpPPltoyBWIKIf2NQH9kHqHa2gwoPg34LTutV9AACTWuiVOjqU7Gq2BHQcjovXMF8t3Wiw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>9NiLuI9TjNvpAPQqD9ySdMX37OmEDCF02isoovt8hwPpiXcZYH4FeasNZoydRrBUOHTTRrW3xdUYGsCZI0H9tSg+gIjo/k/JhmECT7RuSgjEL7mLpusAhi1RFv81TNERGvWP8V9HtB4oZONgOpdTuNqJwhyZ3+aA3zyy7k1mKJc=</P><Q>wqJndWnlZ2i8sW8zhX9SPUddyf8E+wHek3SYynUNQ3T7zJbk+woqyjMuSImXXuZO47uBJlwskYwR+mJr/AuCR7Y0+jtByJF8RoqkY7ttdhS8CpJ9J2o5YMGcGw0JoJ16L0W6QvhY5Zxb5IAG5nuiPLDlgZYNo7+oKRcDyF+fbC0=</Q><DP>hwimhjMFsTnXV19Rk03it+Q2x8JBwS7ycyA6WSi5lPzjX5z/sefOvTtJOLV0R/gXestzehveLo1Hrflqe7d5ZN+9GMZpOVhnnGUEEVFBQjNzf56lFnmk4Fs9zaESlDr5ZBTqPgR+VygKvxlniOjMk7ZzI0sC0ikeCgA/7o1hOiE=</DP><DQ>Fpj2fBpcaSIu7kbj63b53GWBzScPs/jml6Ys6yyl6pQVfA507XSjvTAuCnv3GCyTMjud5g9DmW5y0+hDc1L+wEa2ZeslWx0RGbuVFIM5VUFZB700TLQ3jzVLY5Si7oP6IKzu0EG3SIlb3e7DXlUyY+uB6ga69K0W4BZs+QGpJ80=</DQ><InverseQ>nob08brDfoswDV8JAkGJIg5T9ktMBRzn5djbAfSorOCCVwW+iRz/hkzSs4LaeMuoC3V5AnLeTg1T7J3op67KGerRwwjXSgCKO4crs2pODcZuIMkaE8e/5Ti1O40yKl05mQaxLk/SgSAhy97HhHoiteg/ttLcrvsCcSfyyxzHT3M=</InverseQ><D>bwqYEbh7EjOa3gfIiRBtMIWFExtBD6zZ9dtH0i0FNvZpy8B38iqXirMImcohNxal0fN3BTGc/ft33sJQDABzQlaTnhLgLU1lU9aqeb1fhANjVzPuKhUbhm/2mFeNFfcyCDUDC7y3Zz19hB7BKAomjSQjZKnNAAo2z2e2T9Mzf5kV8uuYsnoum6LEvEfluQ3q3+9Ua64P0E4D2j2iaOnvpBzTCpeaBMDfWZEe19MaS40d/OrZOwlyAVPCW9RkT3948fC5KDvE0KetYDsrVApRSKzvBUQCVNmcO2o+rhMO1qKvS+zkw2VW5OxGDk/QuHuXIkCyipUEMa/DmK74hoxCaQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

Comment: From this big messy wall of unreadable data I was able to find only two lines of issue "description", which didn't help much. Please, elaborate your question better (and apply some formatting as well).

Comment: Well I would imagine if you show us the `C#` decryption code as well, you might increase the likelyhood of getting an answer rather than a **guess**

Comment: If you're encrypting with RSA, you might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34088308/2224584

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a really old version of phpseclib since phpseclib has had built in support for the XML format for quite a few years. So my first recommendation would be to upgrade to the latest version. After that you should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$plaintext = 'zzz';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('<RSAKeyValue>        
    <Modulus>uidt3bPfWozkIkC6nHnRDbXrvjqplfCslV2zP4hKJ6sVjVnPfjMM0ueCuEDFZ9NK+kCWaPNAVhOKKwL8HmoX/7KcFLWkwSoatnrncHTH5STey+bqR1xTFY+Rubj8BZt7D9JJYyLQC46wn4ySVnLWkCZZ9+aaTriEBzGTpUzeRiUTWVprp3oXsA7ZKyn+lhZfMx1ILhcD8dnX7xFHB57jIKvPBxAdT4K7GxdgENeS76I/zmVmlF//JnmtZ/RM1WmRkx8mFmcK/Ky8gLsmIpPPltoyBWIKIf2NQH9kHqHa2gwoPg34LTutV9AACTWuiVOjqU7Gq2BHQcjovXMF8t3Wiw==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>');

define('CRYPT_RSA_PKCS15_COMPAT', true);

$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

echo base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($plaintext));
```

If that doesn't work it'd help to see the .NET code you're using to decrypt. Also, if you could encrypt a string in .NET and post the public key you used to do the encryption and the ciphertext itself that'd be useful. From that I could play around with the phpseclib options until I found some combination of options that let me decrypt the string, which would, presumably, in turn, give us insight in how to encrypt the string.