# PHP openssl_encrypt and NodeJS cipher not having same output

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl

Below are two versions of codes that encrypt a text string. One is using Node JS, the other is using PHP. I am not sure why the output is different, where I expect the output should be the same.

Nodejs v11.9.0

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const secret_data = 'httpswwwcom';
const CIPHER_METHOD = 'aes-256-ctr';
const key = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
const iv = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(CIPHER_METHOD, key, iv);
const encrypted = cipher.update(secret_data , 'ascii', 'ascii') + cipher.final('ascii');
console.log(Buffer.from(encrypted).toString('base64'));
```

PHP 7.3.2

```
const secret_data = 'httpswwwcom';
const CIPHER_METHOD = 'aes-256-ctr';
const key = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
const iv = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
$encrypt= openssl_encrypt(
    secret_data ,
    CIPHER_METHOD,
    key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    iv
);
echo base64_encode($encrypt);
```

Nodejs output is:
`Jx0UQhAEJSQ8Cwo=`

PHP output is:
`p50UwhAEJSS8C4o=`

I have tried updating the encodings (e.g. from Ascii to latin1, or utf8, or binary), but I couldn't make my NodeJS output the same with PHP.

What do I need to do or modify my NodeJS codes to match the output from PHP?

Comment: I dont know how how work the encription on Nodejs... but check the `createCipheriv` function if your original `iv`  still 
 a string or the function convert your original `iv` to hex or whatever.

Comment: @MTK When check the documentation for both Node and PHP, both the IV and Key can be accepted as string. If I convert IV to hex in Nodejs like Buffer.from(iv).toString('hex'), NodeJS will throw Error: Invalid IV length

Comment: I know that can be accepted as string but mi question is if `createCipheriv` don't change (inside on process) your original string to another type. I do'nt suggest you to change manually the `iv` type. I suggest to chek inside `createCipheriv` function if your original `LTvVTPHXt1tXJj5H` still the same as you imput (sorry for mi English)

Comment: Is there a way to check? Because crypto.createCipheriv comes with nodeJS not 3rd party library I have installed.

Comment: have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027847/aes-encrypt-in-php-with-openssl-decrypt-in-node-js)